I rely too much on counting beats, how can I improve?
I believe I have some actual mental deficiency in that field. I have always had troubles understanding the "timing" in a song (edit: sorry, not in the sense of falling on the beat, but more like losing the sense of which beat I am on in a bar, confusing the 1 for the 2 for example). In school I remember the teacher was playing a piano intro before we started singing, and everybody intuitively knew when the singing would start and I didn't, over and over.
When I was learning drums in a small band, I could still mess up a drum fill and not know if I had ended on the one or the two (it was quite bad). So I tried to rely on counting beats but it was not really enough.
I have the same trouble today at 40. I play in a drum band, and I am doing ok now but I am lacking the ability to learn things simply by ear for example. If the teacher plays something, quite often I am unable to play it back, as if my sound memory was too bad, unless I rely on a mental picture of the score, which I am good at now, but it is only a clutch and works mostly for simple stuff.
Also this is impossible for improvisation, as I won't be able to keep count of the bars if it is not at least a little intuitive. Beginners do a much better job at improvising rhythms by ear than me after 10 years of practice.
The advice I got from my current teacher is to let go of the counting, and get into the music and "feel" it. So to put it simple, that "feeling" does not happen for me, and this is where I am at. Does anybody have an idea how I could improve in this field other than counting? Have you ever encountered this problem?

I disagree with your teacher. I’ve never had success learning or teaching a rhythm by just feeling it. Counting with subdivisions and counting beats while clapping rhythms are the best ways to build rhythmic vocabulary that I have experienced and used as a student and teacher. Set a metronome to 60, count “1 + 2 +… “(etc) and clap rhythms (google “rhythms every drummer should know” and stuff like that). Do 30-60 minutes a day and you’ll be more comfortable very soon.

Pros will tell you that you can’t rely “too much” on counting. They are counting subdivisions almost all the time. Classical conductors and musicians, concert band directors and musicians, Broadway artists, probably even some rock stars (I bet the best drummers do it). It’s a fundamental musical skill that is expected of music majors in their first year of college and throughout.

It's a rare problem indeed. Rather like the inability to sing in tune. But it happens, and in my experience, there's no real cure, sorry. I've had students who could not keep time and were unaware of where 'one' was in the bar, or where a sequence started or finished. Rather like me trying to dance with two left feet. I sympathise, but would love to read about a successful remedy. Those students who read well counted throughout, but couldn't do a thing when the dots were taken away, and I never found a realistic solution.

I'm really curious about how you experience rhythms when you hear them and then also (separately) when you go to play them the first few times. You've spoken a lot about what you can't do, and I really hear the frustration. I don't see here what it is you're thinking/feeling/experiencing when you're trying to do the skill

Thanks for your answers. In that drum band for instance, I have a really poor memory but my experience seems ok in the moment, or at least I think. So when I am requested to memorize something, I picture the bars in my mind, I picture where each beat is and place the subdivisions between them like small lines on a ruler, and I picture where each accent or filling note falls on that ruler. So I rely on visual memory. So when I need to improvise something that fills just one bar for example, it's more like a real time math problem than music.

Thank you Todd Wilcox, I will try that. More counting out loud and playing at the same time and I will see how it goes.

Do you have more trouble or less trouble with syncopated music with unevenly distributed notes (e.g. Megalovania, not straight 8ths)?

I do. Right now I am posting because I have problems with brazilian popular music. It is syncopated everywhere and the accent is on two and four, and fills end on the three half of the time. For me it is super complicated, but I see beginners have a much better feeling, and they don't even know about music theory, and they wouldn't know where to put the one but they can remember the piece and play along without any problem. I am afraid that in such a case relying on counting might be a burden more than a useful skill. And I also have this problem with simpler stuff.

"I have no problem being on the beat, the problem is knowing where I am in a bar. Most people seem to be able to do this by ear, even people who have no theoretical knowledge of music and don't know what a bar is... My problem is that I have to rely on counting and almost have a mental image of the score, which does not work on the long term. I would like to develop this kind of ear." - That requires active listening and, since that's how I've always listened to music, why I can poorly cover every song from every album I've ever owned with zero practice.

Audioslave - I Am The Highway - Drumless (with scrolling drum score) - Learn when to hit that first note. Counting won't help and neither does the scrolling bar. Took me about year, practicing for four hours a day, with 15y exp.

Some approaches that might bear fruit:

Listen to music and clap along, especially music with a very strong beat. Sousa marches, for example, have a very clear beat. A lot of club dance music also has a very strong beat.
In addition to clapping, tap your foot, pat your knee, walk, march, swing your arms, ... any thing that gets you physically involved with what you're hearing.
Try using a metronome. This gives you an objective, external judge of whether you're "on" or not. Both just clapping (or other movement) along with the basic click can be helpful, in addition to actually playing whatever music you're learning. Remember to work at a variety of different tempos, so you don't get locked into just one.
Count or clap or tap your hip along with your steps when walking. Same but with your heartbeat. This also can help internalize the sense of a regular pulse.
Once you can keep a steady beat, the next step is to begin dividing the beat. For example, have one hand tap twice for each tap of the other hand — the equivalent of quarter notes against half notes or eighth notes against quarter notes. Or, clap the beat and count the subdivisions.
Try recording yourself. This might help identify specific areas of difficulty.

It's my consistent and clear experience that counting out loud — full voice, not under your breath, and not in your head — is immensely helpful in developing the sense of pulse, especially when it comes to divisions of the beat.
Rhythm can be very difficult and slow to learn, as you more than well understand. Remember that it's a physical experience rather than a mental one.

In the last few years I’ve been educated on the importance of subdivisions when counting. If you agree, perhaps add that to point 4?

Oh to be clear, I was suggesting counting the subdivisions. Especially at slower tempos. Below 60 BPM or so it’s hard for even excellent musicians to keep a steady tempo without counting 16th notes (1 e + uh 2 e + uh….)

@ToddWilcox I agree, but given the struggles of the OP, I fear that might be too much for beginning advice. However, I've added to point 5, plus a paragraph about counting out loud, that I think point in the direction of counting in the way you're suggesting.

I like number 5! I noticed I was better 'the other direction' (having a fast one as the base and the other hand being 'slow') so probably need to practise the one I am bad at (having a slow one as reference and tapping fast with the other).

@Emil In my experience, that's pretty common — the "fast" base being easier. I imagine that's why quarter notes are often taught first, then half notes, with eighth notes coming later. Another common instance is when dealing with 3:2 rhythms. Often starting with the 3 and adding the 2 is easier than starting with 2 and adding 3.

Thank you for your answer. Actually I have no problem being on the beat, the problem is knowing where I am in a bar. Most people seem to be able to do this by ear, even people who have no theoretical knowledge of music and don't know what a bar is know when a certain event happens in the music. My problem is that I have to rely on counting and almost have a mental image of the score, which does not work on the long term. I would like to develop this kind of ear.

Try dancing. Especially to a type of music that you enjoy. Moving your body to the beat and having fun while doing it. Exaggerate movements at the start of each bar and phrase. Try adding "fills" (spins, hand gestures, etc) at the end of a phrase. Over time you'll develop a kind-of muscle memory and learn to "feel" where you are in a track.
Some people on a dancefloor seem to know when a song is about to "drop" (the start of a new phrase), not by counting, not because they already know the song, but because they've developed this sense of "feeling" it, which is what I think your teacher is referring to.

Now that I think about it, if I only listened to the drums (or a metronome) I'd probably lose track as well. The trick is to know how (typical, western) songs are built. Usually part of a song is 4 bars long. And typically, a song might features the following chord changes in those 4 bars:

A B C D (a new chord per each bar)
A A B C (two bars same chord, then changes).

A verse could for example be 16 bars long, that is 4x 4 parts. Sometimes it can then also be like this:

A B C D | A B C E
A A B C | A A B D

to add some variation. If you listen to the classic Beatles' song "Let it be", you will hear 8 bars as an intro. After 4 bars the chords repeat. Rather then counting 1234 1234 1234 1234 | 1234 1234 1234 1234 try to listen to those changes in chords to know when the song begins. 95/100 of western music will follow this recipe.

Right! Phrases! Cadences! :)

This seems to answer a very different question than was asked. The question deals with keeping the beat, while this answer deals with keeping the form.

I think this is relevant to the question. There are many ways to connect better to a musical beat, and one way is certainly to understand how the beat is related to other musical elements, including the form. For example, if a student can hear chord changes in a simple 3-chord song, they can link their counting to both beat and chord changes as they learn.

Yes, that was my question. With chords it is much easier indeed, I try to listen to that when I can.

Yes, perhaps the original question's form was slightly misguided, seeking to make-more-perfect something that was not the actual goal... "Bigger picture" is very often the correct re-framing/answer to a naive question.

@Trip now that I read again that you have trouble improvising, pick your favourite baseline from a song and try to imagine it in your head while playing. Maybe that helps.

@infinitezero thanks, I do feel it is easier if I hear a phrase being played in the background.

I am a self-taught (for the most part) Drummer.
As of next month, I will have been doing it for 50 years.
Please let me ask you, do you know the word 'cadence' ?
....it comes to mind because, before I ever had any guidance and/or direction on the drums, I was nearly always tapping my foot, or my pencil on my math book, etc.
I wonder if you did stuff like that.
I have come to understand that a drummers primary job is to keep time (maintain the   "meter").
I suggest beginning with a rudimentary  approach.
Try counting to 4 saying each number at a regulated interval.
It took me awhile, but with PRACTICE....my ability to count, and therefore, keep time, improved.
I hope this was helpful.

Thanks! Just to make sure, I don't have problems being on the beat or keeping time, my problem is that I don't feel the four bar measure when improvising for example. In that rock band I could play a drum fill and end it on the two thinking it was the one and be off by one beat for the next bars. It did not happen all the time but way too often. Now I play in a Brazilian batucada (much simpler and less improv) and weirdly enough I see that I am much better than the others at counting, or even singing a simple rhythm and playing another one at the same time.

For myself, counting out loud while playing, either piano or drums, helped a lot to "internalize" the sense of beats and the bar line.
If I try to describe why counting aloud works better than silently in one's head, I think it is about concentrating all of your mental focus on performance. If you count in your head, it seems like you draw some of your mental focus out of the performance. When you count aloud, it is more like adding another performance element. On piano it is two hands... plus voice. On drums it is two hands, two feet... plus voice. Silent mental counting simply isn't a performance action.
Of course you need to devote some attention to keeping the correct beat number order. But here is the interesting thing. After counting aloud for a bunch of practice sessions, keeping to fairly easy stuff so I could stay coordinated, I started to naturally stop counting aloud. You might say the vocalizing became a bit lazy, not saying every beat, or mumbling it. But at that point I really didn't need it, because the "internalized" beat count started to take over.
I would point out that it probably isn't as important to be aware of literally each numbered beat count, as compared to absolutely sensing the bar line, or rather sensing when you hit beat one.
Another way to work on this sense of the bar line, and develop it in a flexible way that does not require literal beat number counting, is to work on "fills" or "pick up" figures, the technical term is anacrusis, with varying lengths leading into beat one.
For example, in 4/4 time, you can play little 2 or 4 bar patterns of practice material, and then when you are about to repeat those patterns use a fill to lead into beat one. Sometimes practice a one beat fill, other times a two beat fill, or even a full bar of filler.
In terms of beat number counting those would look like  ...4 | 1, ...3 4 | 1, or 1 2 3 4 | 1 where | is the bar line and the beats preceding it are fill and beat 1 would resume the main pattern. You could count along on just the fill beats, or alternately count the pattern and go silent on the fills.
The idea is to shift from the literal beat counting to a sense of proportion of a bar length: full bar, half bar, last beat of bar. Focus on the sense of beats leading to beat one and crossing the bar line. Instead of counting | 1 2 3 4|, which focuses on beats contained in a bar, as if the activity is tallying a sum, thing of counting ... 2 3 4 | 1, focusing on beats leading to beat one and crossing the bar line, which is fundamentally important for meter and rhythm.

I've had one peer and one student with auditory processing disorder, and your experiences sound like theirs. No matter how much mental gymnastics they do, they physically cannot feel the rhythm and struggle intensely with syncopated rhythms. Even if I had my student have their hands on top of mine while I demonstrated,  my student would say that they could (sometimes) SEE the difference but not FEEL or HEAR it. Other answers have already provided good advice that there is no such thing as "too much counting" and strategies like listening for cadences, so I wanted to chime in with this nugget in case you have never heard of the condition before.
It is not a good/bad situation - let me be clear that you absolutely should carry on as you've been doing for all this time, enjoy your music and enjoy your life with it. If tactile feel of rhythm has been something that has eluded you for your long experience playing music, it could be a processing issue rather than a lack of aptitude. Hope this helps your mental framework about it!
https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/auditory-processing-disorder/symptoms-causes/syc-20555261

Tapping my foot or listening to a metronome while I'm playing guitar helps me keep on beat. It may help, but you'll look pretty foolish clapping. Unless I'm recording or performing, I don't really worry about it, though.
Mixing beats with turntables and a mixer is really good practice. So is dancing -- get a girlfriend. If you still can't feel the rhythm and beat after some time with a mixer and the dance floor, don't quit your day job.
Edit: Practicing with others, like in a band, will help with your rhythm too. You learn to expect what the other people will do and work off of that. Dancing is similar. Sports are a lot like this, as well. The better leader you are, the easier it is to understand the people you're teamed up with. Unless you're doing everything on a computer, you're going to need to understand this, especially if you're having trouble with beats, rhythm, and change-ups after 16/32/64 measures.
